# Design classes/interface to support methods returning different types

Tags: java

I have classes as below.

```
public interface ITest <T>
{
   public Set<T> methodHere();
}

public class test1 implements ITest<String>
{
   Set<String> methodHere(){
      return // Set of String
   }
}

public class test2 implements ITest<Integer>
{
   Set<Integer> methodHere(){
     return // Set of Integer
   }
}

public class ITestFactory {
 public static ITest getInstance(int type) {
  if(type == 1) return new test1();
  else if(type == 2) return new test2();
 }
}
public class TestUser {
    public doSomething(int type) {
       ITest t = ITestFactory.getInstance(type);
       if(type == 1) Set<Integer> i = t.methodHere();
       else if(type == 2) Set<String> s = t.methodHere();
       ...
    }
}
```

There is a warning in the factory class that ITest is used as raw type. What modification should I do to get rid of it?

The TestUser code looks ugly. Am I missing something very basic? I don't want to use `Set<?>`

Thanks
Nayn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a `ITest<?>` to get rid of the warning but probably you want a more strongly type aproach:

```
public class TestFactory {
   public static ITest<?> getInstance(int type) {
      if(type == 1) 
         return new test1();
      else if(type == 2) 
         return new test2();
      else
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type");
   }

   public static <T> ITest<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
      if(clazz == String.class) 
         return new test1();
      else if(clazz == Integer.class) 
         return new test2();
      else 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type");
   }
}
```

Comment: Though this is a good answer, the comment by @Thirler "When you call getInstance it is impossible to know which type will be returned" made me re-think on my design. I am not using generics but created a clean class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there isn't a meaningful replacement for the Generics parameter that would actually be of any specific use, however you can add either `<Object>` or `<?>` to the method signature to get rid of the warning.

The bigger issue with the example code I see is that you're not following [JCC](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/) when naming your classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you call getInstance it is impossible to knwo which type will be returned.

You can however change the signature of the factory method to use generics:

```
public <A> ITest<A> getInstance(Class<A> type)
{

}
```

Comment: This won't help directly since he uses `int` to specify the type. He could of course replace the `int` with a couple `instanceof` checks.

Comment: Yes obviously the implementation would need to change. But the real change is that the calling method needs to know the type that will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

No chance - except from supressing the warning itself. In Java it's not possible in general to declare methods that only have a different return type. And there is no 'escape' by using generics. Methods with the same name that shall return different types need a different argument signature (see: overloading).

If you look at the corresponding byte code, you'll find that `MethodHere` will return an Object. This is called *type erasure*. The generic parameter is only used by the compiler to check/assure type safety.

As always - return a common supertype and have the method caller determine the object type (like used in adapter pattern).